# How can I increase the reach of unarmed strikes (and only unarmed strikes)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, unarmed-combat, reach

I'm working on a build that uses the feats Great Throw and Knock-Down, so even with the errata'd version of Knock-Down I can still deal unarmed strike damage again with almost every attack. Problem is, I want to use a reach weapon for the initial attack (one that can't be used to trip), so I need a way to extend the reach of my unarmed strikes without extending the reach of that weapon, so there's an overlap.

Why can't I just use a different weapon, or no weapon at all? Well, I'm trying to pull this off with Eldritch Glaive (which attacks as a reach weapon), and I assume any trip attacks (which have to be made unarmed since the glaive can't trip) have to actually be within unarmed reach.

Is there anything that extends the reach of unarmed strikes **without extending the reach of reach weapons**?

Comment: Were a warshaper to employ the supernatural ability morphic reach, it seems like the ability would also increase the reach of its reach weapons ("A warshaper of 3rd level or higher can suddenly stretch…, giving it 5 more feet of reach than the creature it's emulating"). Nonetheless, I'm not really clear on why you *wouldn't* want your reach increased all the time, especially if using reach weapon. After all, just because you *can* hit foes that are far away doesn't usually mean you *must.* Could the question explain this process in more detail?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ugh you're right, for some reason I thought Morphic Reach only worked on natural weapons. As for why I need it, as part of a trip attack you need to make an unarmed touch attack, so if you're using a reach weapon to trigger Knock-Down you can't actually (I think) take advantage of your free trip attempt because the target is out of reach of that unarmed touch attack.

Comment: I guess it's a good ask, but it sounds almost contradictory. I mean, the obvious solution is either *Get closer* or *Don't use a reach weapon* then go ahead and increase your reach generally by as much as you want. But, sure, *How can I increase my unarmed strike reach without increasing my overall reach?* is legit. Have fun!

Comment: @HeyICanChan Problem is I want to use it with Eldritch Glaive, which doesn't have any options besides "reach weapon that can't trip"

Comment: It may be worth a separate ask about whether my assumption (trip targets have to be within unarmed reach) is accurate.

Comment: Aha! Mention the glaive in your question! That'll help folks get a handle on what you're after. (Also, consider asking the separate question *Can the benefit of the feat Knock-down be used in conjunction with any weapon or only with weapons that can trip?* I can see going answers going either way on that!)

Comment: Are you attached to your current unarmed strikes, or does it just need to be any strike with reach?

Comment: Just for fun, here's the build I ended up creating (you can view the other entries by clicking the Thread at the top right corner): http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=23999697&postcount=95

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's been 9 months, but I actually found an unambiguous answer.

5 levels in the Atavist prestige class (Races of Eberron pg 133) with the Aggressive Spiritual Lineage/Focus extends the reach of *only* your unarmed strikes and mind blade.

> *Aggressive*: You channel your attacks through your quori spirit, extending your natural reach with your unarmed strike and mind blade attacks by 5 feet.

Comment: Excellent! Very nice find, that.

Comment: Yeah, far too late for the actual build, but it's nice to know there is a way out there. Maybe it'll come in handy some day.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an existing character, or want to start as a normal race: Get a *grappling tentacle* graft installed (Fiend Folio). Cast *extend tentacles* (Savage Species), and *permanency* (explicitly called out as allowed).

Et voila, natural attacks with ten-foot reach that do not affect weapon reach. Note that this is a pricey option, and you can get cheaper versions if you are willing to spend feats or other character options.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that using the Eldritch Glaive is a full round action. It makes many feats, spells and powers invalid in this case. You could use a quickend spell or psionic power, but they would either have limited uses per day or would cost a lot of gold if it was a magic or psionic item.

### Fixing the problem with one simple feat.

If the biggest problem is having an enemy in reach of both the glaive and unarmed attacks, you may consider **Shorten grip** feat (Dragon Compendium) . Since Eldritch Glaive is treated as a glaive, this feat should work for it. It allows you to treat the weapon as it wasn't a reach weapon, but it imposes -2 penalty to such attacks.

### Using a stance

**Dancing Blade Form** (Tome of Battle) is a 5-th level stance from the school of Iron Heart. It increases your reach by 5 feet. Activating it is a swift action, so you could initiate it after the attack with the glaive.

Comment: Does that work? Eldritch Blast (and by extension Eldritch Glaive) isn't a weapon-like effect, and so typically feats like this don't work for it. EDIT: I think it does! Genius!

Comment: Shorten Grip does not work on _eldritch glaive_. _Eldritch glaive_ isn't an actual weapon, you just get to use it as if it were one for the purposes of attacks. How far that goes is debatable but Shorten Grip is going vastly farther than I have ever seen anyone allow it.

Comment: Just for fun, here's the build I ended up creating using your suggestion (you can view the other entries by clicking the Thread at the top right corner): http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=23999697&postcount=95

Answer (score 0):

#### The Bloodwind spell from the Spell Compendium is your friend.

In part, the spell is described as follows:

> The subject can take a full attack
> action to use all of its natural weapons
> or unarmed strikes as if they were
> thrown weapons with a 20-foot range
> increment. The subject gestures as if
> making a melee attack, but the result
> of the attack affects a target within
> range. This spell does not actually
> grant reach....

The action limitation of a full attack action might bother some, but otherwise this might be just the ticket.

As a first level spell, it is pretty cost effective to make it into an at will magic item.

You might want to pair it with some action granting effects.

---

The nice thing about this effect is that it can count as both ranged and melee, if not in the same round, unless you use effects which grant extra actions, same as for the glaive.

Comment: Sadly using the Eldritch Glaive is a fullround action.

Comment: That's why you make it an at-will magic item. The cost increase isn't as bad as normal because it's a first level spell. Pair it with some action granting effect. This allows you to use it with the glaive.

Comment: Bloodwind requires you to use a fullround action. Eldritch glaive also requires you to use a fullround action. You'd need to make 2 full round actions in a single round.

Comment: Entirely doable, if pricey.

Answer (score -1):

Lords of Madness p. 180 has the Aberrant feat **Inhuman Reach**.

It increases your reach by 5 ft. by elongating your arms, making you obviously, well aberrant. It comes with the Prerequisite of Aberration Blood (another feat in that book) and, sadly, you take a -1 penalty on all melee attack rolls.

Probably for having rubber tentacle arms, or something.

Comment: Ummm... Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @MrHiTech Not my downvote, but I expect this answer was downvoted because the Inhuman Reach feat increases the creature's overall reach and the question asks for ways to increase the creature's reach only for its unarmed strike. (Yes, the question's an odd one—see my comment on the question beginning, "I guess it's a good ask,…"—, but it's valid, and this answer was posted before the asker mentioned the reach issue had to do with *eldritch glaive.*)

Comment: @HeyICanChan ahh. Missed that.