# Ways to extend my natural (non-weapon) reach?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, reach

I have a character who has taken Inhuman Reach from *Lords of Madness* and Deformity (Tall) from *Heroes of Horror*, and is two levels away from warshaper 3rd and the morphic reach feature from *Complete Warrior*. I have the long arm fiendish graft from *Fiend Folio*. All told, I’ll have a natural reach of 25 feet.

I want more.

What other options—aside from the obvious one of growing in size myself—offer more bonuses to reach? I’m aware of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148968/4563) seeking ways to increase reach for unarmed strikes only, but again, that’s unarmed strikes *only*—I want this for everything (and actually the atavist option in the accepted answer is not useful to me, as I’m using claws rather than unarmed strike).

Non-epic 3.5e material (including 3.5e-legal 3e material) from Wizards of the Coast sources and/or *Dragon* or *Dungeon* magazine are acceptable. Homebrew and 3rd-party material (including 3rd-party material that licenses the D&D logo) is not. Epic material may be presumed to not exist.

Feats and class features are ideal. Meeting prerequisites may be left as an exercise to the reader, so long as they do not require an epic character or epic stats.

Items are also welcomed for this purpose. Spells and other limited-duration effects (including item effects, for activated items) are only acceptable if they last a day or more. Persistent Spell and other ways of persisting effects are not acceptable. Abusing *polymorph any object*’s poorly-defined duration rules is also not allowed.

For that matter, turning into another creature with longer reach is not acceptable. I want to add the bonus to my own reach, not turn into something else. Size increases are also unacceptable—I’ll no doubt be doing that too but that’s a separate concern.

Infinite and arbitrary loops, *manipulate form*, “unleveling,” and outside assistance are all banned as well.

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for something like the *tentacle extension* (illithid) (*Underdark* 75) (32,000 gp; 2 lbs.) except for all natural weapons instead of just one tentacle? (Really not trying to answer in comments. Seriously, the question's requirements are so specific that I want to confirm that readers are on the same page as the asker.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes, stuff that applies to everything. I appreciate the mention of the _tentacle extension_, because I am also interested in that, but that isn’t part of this question.

Comment: A few more questions like this, and you'll have given the community a foolproof template for what "no cheese" means.

Comment: Does Savage Species count under your *3.5e-legal 3e material* clause?

Comment: @martixy Yes, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extended reach** from *Savage Species* [p.34]
(which you said is valid under the *3.5e-legal 3e material* clause)

The finicky part is meeting the prerequisites. Or in a sense having what you want increased meet the prereqs.

You said meeting those can be left as an exercise to the reader, so we could leave it at that, but I can offer some ideas, though I might be *reaching* a bit.

In your case specifically, your character already has the Aberration Blood feat. One of the options granted by that feat is "flexible limbs" which could potentially be interpreted to cover Extended reach's prereqs.

If you accept that, but your character is not humanoid, being unable to take Aberration blood, apart from the obvious solution (making it humanoid), you have the **Mourning Mutate** feat from *Dragon #359* p.110, which counts as Aberration blood, but can be taken but non-humanoid creatures as well and also features an option called "Unnaturally flexible".

Comment: This actually works fantastically well for my character, who is a warshaper. Thanks.

Comment: That seems reasonable as well. To add a small comment: The reason I passed over Warshaper in my own research on reach is being (Su), so magical. [Vile] feats like Deformity (Tall) are also Su. It broke the all-natural mutant vibe I was going for. Might be relevant for someone else too.